# jQuery plugins cling on, even where they are not sourced through the script tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am building an HTML page (page A) which uses photos as links. On click, information pops up about the photos. To make pop-up forms I used external jQuery plugins. When I navigate to the page all pages seem fine but when I linked back from page A to previous pages, the jQuery plugins clinged on and ruin the page.

Is it because the plugins are stored in cache because I tried

`<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content= "no-cache">`

to stop caches from storing in. I even tried PHP methods and running scripts like `localstorage.clear()`.
I also tried refreshing the page through

`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0">`

because manual refreshing was doing the trick.
Please tell me why is this happening.

EDIT 1

Here are the plugins in case they are of any help.

```html
<link rel=stylesheet href= http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: if you do ctrl+F5 the page won't use cache when it refreshes.  This should work on most browsers and you can see if the page is still messed up.  If it is then there is something else causing the issue.  [More information here including how to do this on mac](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Bypass_your_cache)

Comment: Is there any way you can show us the site or markup?

Comment: Here is a link which shows what happens to the Main page after running through page A. https://goo.gl/photos/qoM1UJEmPoT6M88BA